# Como posso ordenar um LinkedList?

Tags: java, lista

Então como eu disse no título preciso ordenar um `LinkedList` de um objeto e estes objetos como um parâmetro de ordenação.

Segue o código:

```
 public LinkedList getOrderOfActivityCompletion() {
        LinkedList<Activity> activityOrder = new LinkedList<>();

        if (!activityList.isEmpty() && !times.isEmpty()) {

            for (Activity a : activityList.values()) {

                activityOrder.add(a);


            }

        } else {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
        }
        return activityOrder;
```

Preciso fazer 2 (dois) FOR para ordenar este `LinkedList`?

Comment: Você pode usar o [`Collections#sort`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29).

Answer (score 2):

Tomé, para esta situação de simples ordenação, você não precisa implementar toda uma lógica de comparação, o próprio java já fornece apis para ordenação de listas através do método `Collections.sort()`, este método oferece 2 opções de parâmetros, a primeira que demonstro abaixo, é para as situações onde sua classe já implementa a interface `Comparable`:

```
LinkedList<String> lista = new LinkedList<>();
Collections.sort(lista);
```

Caso a classe não implemente `Comparable`, então será necessário implementar uma `Comparator`, que pode recebido tranquilamente pelo método `sort` como uma classe anônima:

```
LinkedList<String> lista = new LinkedList<>();
Collections.sort(lista, new Comparator<String>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(String objetoUm, String objetoDois) {
        // Sua implementação de comparador aqui
        return objetoUm.compareTo(objetoDois);
    }
});
```

Neste trecho de código, estou utilizando a implementação de `compareTo` da própria `String`, mas você pode implementar da forma que preferir.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode implementar direto dessa forma.

Collections.sort(quotas, (a, b) -> a.getName().compareTo(b.getName()));;